# Php __get and __set magic methods - why do we need those here?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magic-methods

On Zend Quick Start Guide here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html we can see:

```
class Application_Model_Guestbook
{
    protected $_comment;
    protected $_created;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_id;

    public function __set($name, $value);
    public function __get($name);


    public function setComment($text);
    public function getComment();
...
```

I normally create my getters and setters without any magic method. I've seen this on the quick guide, and I don't understand why may we need this.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It reduces typing. That's it.

Comment: So on the same place I normally do: $object->setComment('hello'), I can instead do: __set($_comment, 'hello'); ? I believe this is not what you are referring to, because I'm not reducing typing. Thanks again.

Comment: you don't call `__get` and `__set` directly. You'd just do this: `$object->_comment = 'hello';`

Comment: @MEM: Even better:  If the getter and setter are as cool as i'd make them, then instead of `$object->setComment('hello');`, you can say `$obj->comment = 'hello';`.  The setter would look for a method named `setcomment` (case insensitively, cause that's how function/method lookups work) and call `$this->setComment('hello')` for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You (usually) never call `__set` or `__get` directly. `$foo->bar` will call `$foo->__get('bar')` automatically if `bar` is not visible and `__get` exists.

In the tutorial you've linked to, the getter and setter get set up to automatically call the appropriate individual get/set functions. So `$foo->comment = 'bar'` will indirectly call `$foo->setComment('bar')`. This isn't necessary... it's only a convenience.

In other cases, `__get` can be useful to create what looks like a read-only variable.

Answer (score 9):

If you "make your own" getters and setters, you'll be making two functions for each property: `getPropname()` and `setPropname`.  By using PHP's "magic method" setter/getter, you don't write individual methods for each property.  You can set/get properties as if they were public.  Within the overload functions, you add the logic specific to each property.  Example:

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
 switch ($name) {
   case 'comments':
     // do stuff to set comments
     break;
   case 'parent_user':
     // do stuff to set parent user
     break;
 }
}
public function __get($name) {
 switch ($name) {
   case 'comments':
     // do stuff to get comments
     break;
   case 'parent_user':
     // do stuff to get parent user
     break;
 }
}
```

Now I can access comments by using `$obj->comments` to either set or get.

To achieve the above functionality without using the overloads, I would have had to write 4 different methods instead.  This is really more about code organization, both in terms of the actual file and in terms of creating a standardized interface for objects within a project.

I personally prefer to do as you do and write separate methods for each property that I need a complex getter/setter.  To me, it is more clearly organized, and there is a clear separation between "simple" properties of an object and those properties which have greater complexity or one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The `__get` and `__set` magic methods exist for **TWO** reasons:

1. So that you don't have to spend time creating vanilla accessor methods for all of your properties.
2. To allow you to implement property overloading.

If you have properties that need special treatment, then the magic methods are not for you. However, if your properties simply contain data and there are no dependencies then there's no reason NOT to use the magic methods.

Comment: Can you please provide a versus scenario between those cases when we use magic methods and those when we don't use them. (a simple one). thanks again.

Comment: Honestly I think the PHP manual does a pretty good job of explaining magic methods with examples: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: I don't agree. :( Unfortunately I found that documentation quite confusing and since they are so many concepts not explained, they assume that only experimented programmers can talk about magic methods. Perhaps. But on a newbie point of view, it's kind a hard.  But your comment on my question have help me clarifying a little.

Answer (score 1):

Further on the tutorial it gets you to modify the `__get()` and `__set()` methods so you'll see why they're there.

Having magic handling like that can allow you to do some neat stuff like even making "read only" properties and can prevent you from bloating your class with a messy load of getter/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into problems when you've used `__set` and want to override the setter functionality in a child class. You'll have to copy the entire code in `__set` and change only the specific part instead of just simply overwrite one specific setter function -> redundant code

This problem can be avoided by calling the specific `setter` in `__set` (thanks to [cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao) for the tip).

Example:

```
class Foo1 {
   protected $normal;
   protected $special;

   public function setSpecial($special) {
      if ($special == isReallySpecial()) {
         $this->special = $special;
      }
   }

   public function __set($key, $value) {
      switch ($key) {
         case 'normal':
            $this->normal = $value;
            break;
         case 'special':
            $this->setSpecial($value);
      }
   }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
   public function setSpecial($special) {
      if ($special == isNotReallySpecial()) {
         $this->special = $special;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that in this case, the `__get` and `__set` methods probably just call the getter or setter, respectively, since they're specified as well.  In such a case, you have `$obj->property` and `$obj->{get|set}Property(...)` that are consistent, and this problem doesn't exist.