# Practical applications of PHP magic methods - __get, __set, and __call

Tags: php, magic-methods

I've generally tried to stay away from PHP's magic methods because they seem to obfuscate an object's public interface.  That said, they seem to be used more and more, at least, in the code I've read, so I have to ask: is there any consensus on when to use them?  Are there any common patterns for using these three magic methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780386/php-get-and-set-magic-methods-why-do-we-need-those-here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`__call()`**

I've seen it used to implement behaviors, as in add extra functions to a class through a pluginable interface.

Pseudo-code like so:

```
$method = function($self) {};
$events->register('object.method', $method);
$entity->method(); // $method($this);
```

It also makes it easier to write mostly similar functions, such as in ORMs. e.g.:

```
$entity->setName('foo'); // set column name to 'foo'
```

**`__get()/__set()`**

I've mostly seen it used to wrap access to private variables.

ORMs are the best example that comes to mind:

```
$entity->name = 'foo'; // set column name to 'foo'
```

Comment: Interesting.  Could you flesh out your __call() example a bit more?  I'm a bit fuzzy on what $method and $entity actually are.

Comment: $entity: whatever is your object. `__call()` calling the requested method with input args. $events object something along the lines of symfony's event manager, WP do_action(), etc.

Comment: I've seen __call used for horizontal code reuse. This gap will be filed by `traits` but I've seen clever implementation of `__call` to try to emulate `traits`.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is that you do not need to type as much. You could use them for, say, an ORM record and act as implicit setters/getters:

using `__call()`:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setName("Foo Bar");
$user->setAge(42);
$user->save();
```

using `__set()`:

```
$user->name = "Foo Bar";
$user->age = 42;
```

which maps to a simple array:

```
array(
    "name" => "Foo Bar",
    "age"  => 42
)
```

It is much easier to write such an array to the database than doing a lot of manual calls to collect all needed information. `__set()` and `__get()` have another advantage over public members: You are able to validate/format your data.

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to do things like this:

```
class myclass {
    private $propertybag;

    public function __get($name) {
        if(isset($this->propertybag[$name]) {return $this->propertybag[$name];}
        throw new Exception("Unknown property " . (string) $name);
    }

 }
```

Then you can populate `$propertybag` from a SQL query in a single line, rather than setting a whole bunch of properties one by one.

Also, it allows you to have specific properties which are read-only (ie don't allow them to be modified via `__set()`). Maybe useful for an ID field, for example.

Also, you can put code into `__get()` and `__set()`, so you can do something more complex than just getting or setting a single variable. For example, if you have a `storeID` field, you may also want to provide a `storeName` property. You could implement that in `__get()` via a cross-reference lookup, so you may not need the name actually to be stored in the class. And of course `storeName` would not want to be implemented in `__get()`.

Lots of possibilities there.

There are of course some down-sides of using magic methods. The biggest one for me is the fact that you lose the auto-complete functionality in your IDE. This may or may not matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since magic methods can save you a LOT of coding when it comes to repetitive tasks like defining members, populating them and then retrieving them - instead of doing that boring, long piece of work, you can use mentioned 3 methods to shorten the time to code all that. If needed, I can provide a few examples tho they can be found in various tutorials over the net.

I don't know if it's general consensus, but the usual should apply - use where appropriate. If you find yourself to do repetitive task (define member, populate member, get member, call X functions that differ slightly) - magic methods might help you.

Comment: Boring work isn't a good reason to use magic methods. These methods makes the code harder to understand."call X functions that differ slightly" is especially a case where you have to be explicit about the "slightly". Magic methods should be used on few cases, like when the attribute list of an object is **dynamic** (like in the case of an ORM).

Comment: So if you have 100 possible members of a class that you will need, you won't bother to use magic methods __set and __get to speed up that boring work, you'll explicitly define them one by one? I think not. So I don't agree with you. Magic methods should be used where appropriate and where they help speed up the work. If you feel opposite - well, it's your time, not mine :)

Comment: @Michael J.V.: If you have 100 possible members you're likely __doing it wrong__.

Comment: Since when have programmers stopped thinking abstractly? Do I really have it wrong if I'm doing an ORM where I don't know how many table columns / tables / databases I might have? Is it really needed to explicitly define every possible scenario before comments such as yours stop coming? No, I'm not doing it wrong. Also, doing an ORM is just one thing where you are expecting variable amount of possible attributes. If it's 2 or a 1000, it doesn't matter if it's a variable amount of needed members.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say it's a matter of dynamism, in this case?  It's impossible to explicitly write setters/getters for an ORM because, by definition, the map is dynamic.  There's no way to know ahead of time the number of members that would need to be generated or accessed.

Comment: @Michael J.V.: That was merely a comment on having 100 members in an ORM instance. ORM usually map to a data source and if your data source has 100 'columns' as in the case of a database table, then its probably time to re-think your data structure.

Comment: Care to provide reasons why? Have you never seen database tables with over 100 columns? If you have limited experience with something, don't assume you're just right. Have you ever seen a medical database and how many columns tables have there? No, it's not time to rethink data structure, it's absolutely careless to assume things you are assuming.

Comment: @Michael J.V.: Yes I'd do 100 getter and setter. Maybe I'd generate the code, but yes, definitely. The less magic there is in the code, the most readable and easier to understand it is. Would you prefer a `__set()` method with a massive `switch($member) { case 'name': /*  some stuff */; break; case 'age': /* other special process */; break; /* Add 98 others case here */ }` ? Not me, and I believe the people that will end up maintaining code like that either.

Comment: So you find it easier to code generate 100 setters and 100 getters than have a single point of entry where you can define extra caases trough switch case? And you didn't pause for a second to think whether you're right or not in your statement? It screams "terrible idea" no matter how you look at it! I still stand by my statement - I'd use magic functions IF they are appropriate. My first choice would be a public member that's an array before actually using __get and __set that'd act as my placeholder. If not possible I'd use magic methods. But code generate 100 methods...

Comment: `<precision> Code generating from the private attribute just the first time <I write the class.</precision>` Only speaking of readability and ease of understanding the code, yes, explicitly declaring getters and setters is better. Try to understand business classes of Magento, I think you'll understand my point. Why is it bad from your opint of view ? Too much char to type with your keyboard ? Too long class file ? I sincerely don't get it.

Comment: You don't get why I find it bad to type 100 members, 100 setters and 100 getters if I can do it in less than 10 lines of code in total? It's more readable to you to have 100 setters / getters / members than to group similar tasks in two magic functions? I'm amazed. What you are saying makes absolutely no sense and defeats purpose of programming. I'm sorry but I can't take you seriously so I'm stopping this debate here.

Answer (score 0):

One common pattern is to have a single handle for your clients and proxy the calls to encapsulated objects or singletons based on naming conventions or configurations.

```
class db
{
    static private $instance = null;

    static public function getInstance()
    {
        if( self::$instance == NULL )
            self::$instance = new db;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    function fetch()
    {
        echo "I'm fetching\n";
    }
}

class dataHandler
{
    function __call($name, $argv)
    {
        if( substr($name, 0, 4) == 'data' )
        {
            $fn = substr($name, 4);
            db::getInstance()->$fn($argv);
        }
    }
}

$dh = new dataHandler;
$dh->datafetch('foo', 'bar');
```

Same principles can be used to drive different backends of the same functionality without having to change the driver.

Comment: This would have been easier without magic methods using simple polymorphism. You are re-inventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you'd like, as long as the magic properties/methods are documented; undocumented magic should be avoided unless working with a very abstract layer of code, such as when developing an ORM.

**acceptable at an abstract layer**

```
/**
 * DB backed model base class.
 */
class Model {
    protected $attributes = [];

    function __get($name) {
        return @$this->attributes[$name];
    }
}
```

**acceptable when documented**

```
/**
 * User model backed by DB tables.
 * @property-read string $first_name
 * @property-read string $last_name
 */
class UserModel extends Model {

}
```

**lazy and unacceptable (and common when using ORMs)**

```
/**
 * This class is magical and awesome and I am a lazy shithead!
 */
class UserModel extends WhoCaresWhenEverythingIsMagical {

}
```